# Can address of a variable change after Garbage Collector finishes its job in R?

Tags: r

If possible, I would like to know if the Garbage Collector (GC) changes the address of a variable in R. In other words, assuming the following code:

```
library(pryr)

x <- 0:1024

addr <- address(x)  # save address of variable "x" in "addr"

    .
    .
    .
*(execution of operations that creates/destroys many small/big objects in memory, which will likely make the GC to be called...)*
    .
    .
    .

if (addr != address(x))
{
   print("Address of x changed!")
}
```

Will the message `Address of x changed!` be ever printed?

Comment: The garbage collector by itself doesn't change variable addresses. An object can change address due to the pass-by-value copy-on-modify R semantic or if it is redefined. So, if `x` stays unchanged during the calculation it won't change address (regardless whether the garbage collector has been called); otherwise it might be.

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure about R, but in general it is possible. A GC could move an object for several reason. for example, move objects from nursery space to mature space (generational GC) or using mark-compact/semispace technique to sweep dead objects.